# How do I make `read` fail when another process writes to the file?

Tags: c, linux

Lets say I open up a binary file (or text as binary) and read 16K bytes. Another file opens the process and truncates it, appends, or changes bytes I haven't read (or already read)

Would there be a way to have `read` fail? Currently when I get to the end of the file I do a stat and check if the modification time matches the time I started with but I rather fail sooner than later

Comment: You might be able to use iNotify to do it.  Otherwise, I think the answer is "No".

Comment: With mandatory locks, you could prevent the changes from happening in the first place. Windows has mandatory locks, but I think Linux only has advisory locks. (The question is tagged Linux.)

Comment: Re "*but I rather fail sooner than later*", So stat sooner...

Comment: `man mount`, see options:  "`mand`   Allow mandatory locks on this filesystem.  See fcntl(2)."

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano: And if you in fact refer to `fcntl(2)`, you will see it says that mandatory file locking is deprecated and should not be used.  There is a good reason why it is not enabled by default.

Comment: Using mtime is dicey; there are filesystems where the stored mtime has only one-second granularity or less, so it's entirely possible that a write will not change the mtime.

Comment: Do you control the other process?  If so, then modify both the reader and the writer to lock the file around each access (advisory locks).  Then the problem doesn't arise as the file will not be written while you are reading.  If the writer is not under your control, this gets harder.

Comment: @ikegami from my understand they no longer work on newer linuxes? See barmar comments here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71696378/how-do-i-lock-a-file-so-i-can-read-it-from-start-to-end specifically "
Mandatory file locking seems to be deprecated. man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html says that it requires a kernel configuration option, and this is a step along the way of removing it entirely."

Comment: @NateEldredge no unfortunately not. I imagine people will be using build scripts with the program I'm writing. Some may be homemade

Answer (score 0):

You could use a critical section. I think that's what Nate Eldredge Suggested.

```
Enter critical section
    Read file
Leave critical section

Now you can write
```

Then your "read" will not fail, but there will be no more reason to do so.

Comment: This doesn't work. The writer would need to be in a critical section controlled by the same locking mechanism. And fixing your code won't help because the OP ruled out that possibility.